# Limitations of URL schemes in iOS

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I am experiencing a very strange issue. I have two apps. Each has registered a URL scheme so that when I press a button in one app, it takes me to another app.
The strange thing is jumping from app A to B works, but jumping from B to A doesn't.
I don't want you to help me find the bug if there is any (I can do it myself). 
So I won't post code.

My only question is if there is some systemic limitation in iOS that would prevent apps "pointing" to each other even if they register the scheme properly. I tried to google about such a hypothetical fact but nothing meaningful came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such limitation if the URL schemes are declared and they are unique.

Comment: Right after you answered, I realised that a good example is Facebook and Facebok Messeger jumping back and forth. Ok that was easy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So the problem was that in the other app, **I registered the scheme into the unit tests** `info.plist.` I should have been registering it in the standard target `info.plist.`

It's easy to overlook when you use the bottom search.